# How to convert a 16bit PCM raw audio data to Float32Array to be played by Mozilla Audio API

Tags: audio, mozilla, pcm

I have a byte[] of raw single channel 16KHz 16bit little-endian PCM audio data, in other words it is the data portion of a wav file (format as described above) less the first 44 bytes header.

Now I want to play it with the Mozilla Audio API as indicated in https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API, more specifically with the Audio.mozWriteAudio(buffer) function. From my reading the Mozilla audio api is expecting a Float32Array for the raw data, I saw some example samples, they are between (-1,1).

Now, how do I convert my byte[] to the required Float32Array in Java?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I have the same problem.

Comment: Note: this API has been deprecated in favor of the Web Audio API chosen by the W3C    ... see link in OP question